# Java eclipse application rendering a webpage

Tags: java, eclipse

> ```
>   package com.example.firstTest;
>   import java.awt.TextField;
>   import java.util.List;
>   import java.util.Scanner;
>   public class MyFirstClass {
>        public static void main(String[] args) {
>            // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
>            System.out.println("Enter URL");
>            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
>            String url;
>            url=(scanner.next());
>            System.out.println("url entered "+url);  
>            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));// this open webpage in browser
> }
> ```
>
> }

I have this simple app, it basically asks for the user to enter the url on console.Then it shows the url entered.What i want to do, is when url is typed i open the url via eclipse somehow and check for every page change done on the url.Like say google search click, i want to print page changed sthg.

Comment: "check for every page change done on the url.Like say google search click, i want to print page changed sthg". Can you explain this further?

Answer (score 0):

To load the url from code, you can use a test automation framework such as Selenium WebDriver. However, I am not aware whether Selenium's Recorder API is exposed. 
However, https://github.com/facebook/huxley looks promising. With each record/action you need to do a comparison of DOM to detect page change.